# SQLiteException: no such table

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am using my own SQLite3 database as opposed to creating a new one each time my app runs, as I have a few tables with static data that I am trying to display. I created my database and placed it in my assets folder. I then created my database helper and when I start my app I can open my database without problem but when I try to open my first table using the following code

```
private Cursor getData() 
{
    try
    {
        myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("exhibitor", FROM, null, null, null,null, ORDER_BY);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        return cursor;
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e)
    {
        String err = e.toString();
        return null;
    }
}
```

It throws an error saying `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: exhibitor: , while compiling: SELECT _id, EXHIBITOR FROM exhibitor ORDER BY EXHIBITOR` but when I check the database exhibitor is there.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed a database in the .apk of a distributed application \[Android\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013021/embed-a-database-in-the-apk-of-a-distributed-application-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you moved the database from the assets folder to `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/` on the emulator?

[This is a good detailed post](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) about moving the database to `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/` if it does not exist.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013021/embed-a-database-in-the-apk-of-a-distributed-application-android) is another short and simple solution to it.

Comment: The second link has solved the problem but I will take the advice and create the table on startup and populate the table the first time to prevent the Apk from being too large. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 19):

Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> (Click on your application) -> Clear data

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you create new table in an existing database the table doesnt create because the OnCreate function of database handler will not be called everytime but only if required(like database not initiated). If that is not the case your newly created table actually hasnt created. Clear the data to force the db to instantiate itself.

Answer (score 3):

Clear Data and uninstall application from your device and re-install application in device...

```
Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> Your Application Name -> Clear data
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate()` does not create a new database every time your app starts - rather it creates a database if it does not already exist.

It sounds like you might have an empty database created by or for your helper (if there was no database at all, I might expect a different exception), and your separate database that you created outside of Android. Looks like you and your app are not looking in the same place for your data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you are correct. I have now resolved it by creating the database on startup and populating the data the first time the app is loaded to prevent the Apk from being too large.

Answer (score 1):

Just clearing the data did not work for me.

What worked was:

- Uninstall app
- Restart device or emulator
- Disable Instant run (Not just the main group but all individual instant run settings)
- Build -> Clean Project
- Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

hapend to me once 
change your DATABASE_VERSION

if your DATABASE_VERSION =1 it will see just three table
if your DATABASE_VERSION = 2 it will see just more table but i really didn't know how many

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I just had a simple mistake.

**Reason:**

[image]

**Solution:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me. I don't exactly know why but changing the DB_VERSION attribute to a bigger number made it work. The thing is: each time i'm changing the fields of the DB (attributes of the SQLiteDB class), i need to change that number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer according to the description of @ReivieraKid.

No, Uninstall, No Restart, Just checking the app memory if it is your real database, if return false, then copy the database to the memory again. Then You will All set.  But to apply this method, you have to know the minimum size of your database.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73332470/7608371