# Unable to read SQLite table from Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am trying to open a SQLite database in android, the database works fine in the sqlite browser, but android does not read that the table in question exists. Below is the code I'm tinkering with.

```
public String setColorName() {
    String colorName = null;
    try {
        db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("colors.db",MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null); 
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT colorName FROM Colors WHERE RGB = '000000'", null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    colorName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("colorName"));
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } else {
            colorName = "woops";
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}

    return colorName ;
}
```

I have found many articles regarding this issue on several forums (including stackoverflow) but the 
issue I'm having didn't seem to get resolved with their solutions. I'm trying to pull the RGB and colorname from the code (the query above is just a test leading up to that) so that I can estimate the nearest RGB using the euclidean distance formula on each portion. In order to do that, I need to be able to atleast grab the data from the table :P.

LogCat:

```
    I/Database(12748): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Colors
D/AndroidRuntime(12748): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(12748): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4
0015560)
E/AndroidRuntime(12748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12748): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
 Colors: , while compiling: SELECT colorName FROM Colors WHERE RGB = '000000'
E/AndroidRuntime(12748):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.nat
ive_compile(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12748):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.com
pile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(12748):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<in
it>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
E/AndroidRuntime(12748):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(
SQLiteProgram.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime(12748):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQ
LiteQuery.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime(12748):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDri
ver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime(12748):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQue
ryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
E/AndroidRuntime(12748):        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQue
ry(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
```

And finally, here's a picture of the SQLite browser showing that the query does work on that database
[SQLiteBrowser Query](http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/6327/screenshot2011062509122.png)

Incase the picture didn't give it away, I'm storing the colors.db in assets.

### Sorry for the length, I try to be as thorough as possible and seriously appreciate anyone who helps me.

Ok, it looks like I got past the issue. I needed to copy the db from assets and then open it from there. I ended up making a database helper using the information I found in the link below and I got the database to stop returning that error, though I now need to complete the rest of the application. Thanks a ton for all the great advise, everyone! http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: maybe it's the missing ";" at the end of raw query string.

Comment: Did you create color table from you application?

Comment: No, the table was created using a CSV import through the SQLiteBrowser application in the picture. @Overbose, I tried adding a ; to the end, but it gave the same error

Comment: Android database are linked to the application not with the system.Two applications may have a database with same name.I think the database you created in your application don't have any color table.create it just like you created the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the database and after that you wish to access the table from it. Don't you need to create the tables too? I'd suggest you to use [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) instead of `openOrCreateDatabase` so you won't run into this problem.
If you wanna access an existing database through `assets` (as I've seen on your screenshot), you could refer to [SQLiteException: no such table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991368/sqliteexception-no-such-table)

Comment: I had created a helper, but it seemed like it would be tricky to add in the data from my already created database.

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot it appears you have the colors.db in your assets directory.

While I am not sure exactly how to load a SQLite db from there, I do know that by default the `SQLiteDatabase` android helper object reads and writes to the protected data folder of the app.  So your `openOrCreateDatabase` method is invoking a create.  But it bombs on the query because the table doesnt exist in this freshly minted db.

I'm sure someone else or a little googling can help resolve this further.