# Android Jelly Bean: Database corrupted on upgrade

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade, android-4.2-jelly-bean, corrupt

In my application, I create a database by copying over an existing sqlite database that is saved in my assets folder.

In the code I also check the database version, so if a newer version of the application is installed with a higher database version, then the database is recreated (in the onUpgrade method).

The problem I am experiencing, is that the upgrading process functioned perfectly on previous Android versions, but since installing Jelly Bean, I have been getting an error that the database is corrupted. If I clean install the application (so no database upgrade, just create), then the application also functions normally.

The two devices that I tested it on is an S3 with 4.1.1, and a Nexus 4 with 4.2.1.

Any ideas why it would start failing on the latest Android versions? Thanks!

The error is as follows:

```
01-09 09:59:50.941: E/SQLiteLog(15915): (11) database corruption at line 51776 of [00bb9c9ce4]
01-09 09:59:50.941: E/SQLiteLog(15915): (11) database disk image is malformed
01-09 09:59:50.941: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(15915): Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/data/myapp/databases/services.sqlite
01-09 09:59:50.941: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(15915): deleting the database file: /data/data/myapp/databases/services.sqlite
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/SQLiteLog(15915): (1) no such table: services
01-09 09:59:50.991: D/AndroidRuntime(15915): Shutting down VM
01-09 09:59:50.991: W/dalvikvm(15915): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c3c930)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapp/myapp.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: services (code 1): , while compiling: (my query)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: services (code 1): , while compiling: (my query)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at myapp.c.f(Unknown Source)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at myapp.bk.a(Unknown Source)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-09 09:59:50.991: E/AndroidRuntime(15915):    ... 11 more
```

The code to create, and upgrade the database is as follows:

```
public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();

    if(dbExist) {
        this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    dbExist = checkDatabase();
    SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;

    if(!dbExist) {
        db_Read = this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDatabase();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new Error ("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDatabase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //database does't exist yet.
    }

    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}


public SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    return myDatabase;
}


@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDatabase != null) {
        myDatabase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    sc.updatedDB = true;
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        try { 
            copyDatabase(); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            throw new Error("Error upgrading database"); 
        } 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your onUpgrade method is very strange. As well as the fact that you copy the database file instead of adding new tables and selecting/inserting of data.

Comment: I don't care about saving the data in the database when upgrading, I just require the structure (tables, columns) to be updated, therefore I want to copy the new structure from the sqlite database in the assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this problem by putting a close() statement in your copyDb method before you create the output stream:

```
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

     if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error log says that you should have a table names "services" and it did'nt find it, check your database creation code, maybe you made a mistake in your creation queries.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The same code that creates the database initially is used to recreate it after the upgrade. However, as it creates the 'services' table correctly on clean database creates, I don't think the problem lies there.

Comment: look at this answer, maybe it will help you to solve the problem of non existing table:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4991669/1348478)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your onUpgrade method. It is not working. You can't overwrite db file with new one from onUpdate method. First parameter is a db (SQLiteDatabase db) and it is already opened. So you cant overwrite opened db's file with your new one. Check this in debbuger.

Maybe you have another errors in your code...