# Room and SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException

Tags: android, android-room

Just saw one report in my play console:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: 
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement (Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement (SQLiteConnection.java:903)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString (SQLiteConnection.java:648)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode (SQLiteConnection.java:333)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration (SQLiteConnection.java:298)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open (SQLiteConnection.java:217)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open (SQLiteConnection.java:195)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:503)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:204)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:196)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner (SQLiteDatabase.java:920)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open (SQLiteDatabase.java:908)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase (SQLiteDatabase.java:767)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase (SQLiteDatabase.java:757)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:355)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
  at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)
  at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
  at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query (RoomDatabase.java:233)
  at org.walleth.data.transactions.TransactionDAO_Impl$8.compute (TransactionDAO_Impl.java:1228)
  at org.walleth.data.transactions.TransactionDAO_Impl$8.compute (TransactionDAO_Impl.java:1214)
  at android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run (ComputableLiveData.java:100)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

Anyone knows a good way to deal with these? Especially when using LiveData I do not yet see a good way to handle this problem. Also what would be a good way to reproduce this - so how do I corrupt the database elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone knows a good way to deal with these?

Well, if your database is corrupted, it's corrupted. You probably won't be able to fix it unless you re-create it from scratch. But if you want to check if it's valid before doing anything on it, just refer to this post : [Android: Check if a file is a valid SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576646/android-check-if-a-file-is-a-valid-sqlite-database/39751165)

EDIT: Okay, [it seems it's possible to fix a SQLite database](https://superuser.com/questions/111998/how-do-i-repair-a-corrupted-firefox-places-sqlite-database) but it really depends on how corrupted it is, so chances are you won't write a generic code to fix them.

> Also what would be a good way to reproduce this - so how do I corrupt
>   the database elegantly?

You will have to reproduce it on a rooted phone, because you won't be able to corrupt the database via standard SQLite statements (they're especially made to prevent this).

Take a dummy phone (or emulator), then root it, and access to this file :

```
//data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>
```

You can open it with any editor, and mess with it (delete a bunch of lines then save it). Chances are this will corrupt the file, and you'll have the `SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException`

Comment: Thanks - but this is a general answer to SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException - I am more interested in SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException+room/LiveData. E.g. how to catch this error. Currently I do not even see a way to catch it properly as the database calling code is in room and not directly in my code - so I cannot even wrap it in a try/catch