# Android SQLite full file writing vs Flat File

Tags: android, performance, file, sqlite, flat

Newbie android programmer here.  I've searched to try to find what I'm looking for, but haven't found it exactly.  Please forgive me if this is answered already or too simplistic a question.  The closest is this discussion:  [Android Performance : Flat file vs SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212640/android-performance-flat-file-vs-sqlite)

I've used SQL in the past, and I know that my data would be much better served using a relational database rather than a flat file.  However, there is a need to export the data every day into a CSV, and so I wrote the app to store to a small flat file csv instead.  The file contains customer info like name, balance, phone, address, etc.  Total customers is about 500.  The file is about 30K.

1) I'm wondering what is best practice on an Android device regarding saving data to a file in terms of timing.  Assuming I stick with a flat file, is it better to save the entire file every time the user enters data (once every 30 seconds or so for an hour), or have a timed saving, or have the user save the file?  I can't use onPause/etc. as the app switches between activities frequently and at times when there may be no need to write.

2) Does SQLite on Android write an entire db file every time, or is it less 'disk-intensive'?  IE when i write to the flat file, I have to replace the entire contents every time... does the SQLite write an entire file or is it more similar to an append, and thus less disk intensive?  I understand how the DB works in the memory, but I don't know how it works in terms of disk output.  Wondering about efficiency, even for a small file.  If it's just silly to keep re-writing a flat file vs. a simple one-liner append to a DB file, maybe it's worth setting up a DB and then exporting to the csv.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: considering the amount of data you have, i recommend that you do not worry about the performances, and stick with whatever is more convenient for you.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946298/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-sqlite-rather-than-file

Comment: Thank you both very much.   This is very helpful.  @LS_dev, that link had the answer I was searching for -- according to Chintan Rathod, small writes only via DB, not the whole file.  So it does make a difference depending on size of data for sure.  But, for now, I think I'll take njzk2's advice and keep it to a flat file since the data is so small and I need it in csv anyway.  Thanks again!