# How can i use Sqlite database in my android activity?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity

I am creating a sample application using sqlite database unfortunately I am not familiar in sqlite database concepts. I have the following requirements,

1. I have a sqlite database named as quotes.db. The database having two fields in is number and Quotes. Which is stored in assets folder.
2. In my Activity i have two fields one is edittext and another one is button.
3. When the user enter the value (number) in edittext and click the button. Now I display the corresponding quotes which is stored in database.

if any one having sample code snippet similar to this kindly post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&biw=1280&bih=923&noj=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+sqlite+tutorial&oq=android+sq&aq=0&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=3196l8071l0l10307l8l8l0l0l0l0l2473l2604l0.1.9-1l2l0&gs_l=serp.3.0.0l10.3196l8071l0l10307l8l8l0l0l0l0l2473l2604l0j1j9-1l2l0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) which is an introduction to Android apps and especially to databases in Android.

Quting the website:

> This tutorial on writing a notepad application gives you a "hands-on"
>   introduction to the Android framework and the tools you use to build
>   applications on it. Starting from a preconfigured project file, it
>   guides you through the process of developing a simple notepad
>   application and provides concrete examples of how to set up the
>   project, develop the application logic and user interface, and then
>   compile and run the application.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of creating and accessing a database in android.

**Method 1:** Use simple SQL statements
For that follow this tutorial: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/android-developer-tutorial-part-12.html

**Method 2:** Use a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper
For that follow this tutorial: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

I would recommend you to follow method 2 as that makes it much simpler to query and update your database once it is all set up. Also note that when you move on to 'Content Providers' method 2 will again be very very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Android dev manual has a [useful introduction](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) to the process. Take a look at the [Searchable Dictionary](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/src/com/example/android/searchabledict/DictionaryDatabase.html) for some example code.

I gave an answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013021/embed-a-database-in-the-apk-of-a-distributed-application-android) for importing a database from a file in your assets/ directory.