# how to read/write data dictionary in android programmatically

Tags: android, storage, read-write, data-dictionary

I want to read/write data dictionary in file which is in android internal/external memory. In WP7, they have used IsolatedStorage for storing the dictionary directly. In IOS, they can write NSDictionary directly to the file. Please anyone tell me the way to write DataDictionary into file.

> Note: I have the keys and values in the Map variable.
>   how to store this Map directly to file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest putting your words into a database for the following reasons

> DB lookups on android with SQLite are "fast enough" (~1ms) for even
>   the most impatient of users
>
> Reading large files into memory is a    dangerous practice in
>   memory-limited environments such as android.
>
> Trying to read entries out of a file "in place" rather than "in
>   memory" is effectively trying to solve all the problems that SQLite
>   already solves for you.

[Embed a database in the .apk of a distributed application [Android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013021/embed-a-database-in-the-apk-of-a-distributed-application-android)

You can find more detailed examples by searching **object serialization**

[EDIT 1]

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("1",new Integer(1));
map.put("2",new Integer(2));
map.put("3",new Integer(3));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("map.ser");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(map);
oos.close();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("map.ser");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
Map anotherMap = (Map) ois.readObject();
ois.close();

System.out.println(anotherMap);
```

[EDIT 2]

```
try {

        File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/map.ser");

        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("1", new Integer(1));
        map.put("2", new Integer(2));
        map.put("3", new Integer(3));
        Map anotherMap = null;

        if (!file.exists()) {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(map);
            oos.close();

            System.out.println("added");                
        } else {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            anotherMap = (Map) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();

            System.out.println(anotherMap);
        }



    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

[EDIT 3]

```
Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = meMap.keySet().iterator();
while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
    String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
    String value=(String)meMap.get(key);

     // check for value

}
```

Comment: But if you store your key values in file, it costs too much. I mean when you try to search a word , how you can do this ?

Comment: while storing i have append the key and values with some values, so i can split this

Comment: i don't want to use SQLite storage here. any other option?

Comment: Thank you. "map.ser" where this will be stored? what is ".ser"?

Comment: .ser is meanless, just the shortest word of serialization. Please look at edit 2

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me check this. and i want to know onething, that is how can check keyexists?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if using `SharedPreferences` ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)) is something that is suitable for your usecase.

You store via a key-value pair, and can have multiple `SharedPreferences` per application. While both are stored as `String` objects, the value can be automatically cast to other primitives using built in methods.

Mark Murphy has written a library, `cwac-loaderex` ([link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex)), to facilitate access of `SharedPreferences` via the use of the `Loader` pattern ([link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)), which offsets some of the work you need to do to keep IO off the main thread.