# Missing assets folder and database in apk

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to develop an app with 1 database with 2 tables via a sqliteopenhelper in a databaseadapter class.

```
    DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private static SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context context;

    public DbA(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public DbA open() {
         db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }


    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        private static final String K_I = "_id";
    private static final String K_CC = "cc";
                          private static final String T_DGI = "dgi";

    private static final String CREATE_FIRSTTABLE = 
                "create table if not exists firsttable (" + K_I + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + K_CC + " text not null, "
                + ");";

    private static final String CREATE_SECONDTABLE =  "create table if not exists secondtable (" 
                                  + K_I + " integer primary key  autoincrement, "
    + T_DGI + " text not null, "
     + ");";

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE, null, D_VERS);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {


                          try{
_db.execSQL(CREATE_FIRSTTABLE);                
              _db.execSQL(CREATE_SECONDTABLE);

                          }catch(SQLException e)
                                      { e.printStackTrace(); }          
}

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {



        }

    }
```

Along the way, I have extracted the database via the file explorer in the ddms to insert data manually (for both tables) and push it back into eclipse. All this while, the project worked perfectly in the virtual AVD emulator.

But once I try to use an actual android device to run it, it throws an error with a logcat stating that the secondtable was not found?

08-17 01:48:18.951: E/SQLiteLog(4602): (1) no such table: secondtable
08-17 01:48:18.956: D/AndroidRuntime(4602): Shutting down VM
08-17 01:48:18.956: W/dalvikvm(4602): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f23700)
08-17 01:48:18.966: E/AndroidRuntime(4602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Would really appreciate any ideas as how to go about fixing this.

This is the new logcat reading when clicking on a button within the app that crashes it.. not sure what it means

08-17 02:35:39.631: E/(8527): Device driver API match
08-17 02:35:39.631: E/(8527): Device driver API version: 23
08-17 02:35:39.631: E/(8527): User space API version: 23 
08-17 02:35:39.631: E/(8527): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct 30 09:36:10 KST 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall and reinstall the app on your device.

If the problem goes away, that is because:

- You changed your database schema, adding in `secondtable`,
- You did not update your schema version or implement `onUpgrade()` of your `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and
- Your device already had a version of your app, with a database, created with the earlier schema that lacked `secondtable`

Comment: I've tried updating the version and 'replaying' it on the device. I'm not sure what you mean by 'install and reinstall', but in using the phone as the running android device, all I did was click on the android device chooser and it installs to run on the phone via usb cable? Not sure if it uninstalls properly on the phone tho, but on checking application manager on the phone, the app is not resident.

Comment: I've been considering a method suggested on stackoverflow to just copy the database from the asset folder in the apk directly into the app on runtime (ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013021/embed-a-database-in-the-apk-of-a-distributed-application-android) but on checking the apk, there is no /assets folder?

Comment: @user65163: "I'm not sure what you mean by 'install and reinstall'" -- I mean what I wrote. Go into Settings and uninstall the app. Then run it again from your IDE. This is not the same as just running it from the IDE, which is more like an upgrade-in-place. "I've been considering a method suggested on stackoverflow to just copy the database from the asset folder in the apk directly into the app on runtime" -- please [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). "but on checking the apk, there is no /assets folder?" -- do you have any assets?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works now on the device. But unfortunately, all the data I injected in the database (by extracting, adding data and pushing back to eclipse via ddms) is now missing since the app essentially creates empty tables only.

Comment: @user65163: That's why you need to implement `onUpgrade()` and bump the schema version number in the future, so you can make an in-place upgrade of the database.

Comment: Thanks. I'm kinda new to android so I'm taking it one step at a time. Your suggestion solves part the problem, but I guess I still have to figure out a way to copy the database to the app (on first run). Will look into the sqliteassethelper you suggested. Hope I get it to work